# User input to make substring

Tags: javascript, string, properties

In my program, I have three text fields. In one of them, you are supposed to fill in some text, and in the other two, you fill in two numbers. The text field with the words large number has to have a greater value than the text field with the words smaller number. However, the number has to be less than the length of the user-inputted text.

Whenever I run the program, the javascript console says it cannot read property of sub-string null. 
Here are the relevant bits of my code.

```
<p> Input text, and fill in two numbers in the boxes below. </p>
<p> The number on the left must be smaller than the one on the right</p>
<p> Press on the button to see what happens!
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
var t = document.getElementById("t");
var s = document.getElementById("small");
var l = document.getElementById("large");
function sub_str() {
var short_str = t.substr(s,l);
var regex_num = /^([0-9]*)$/;
if (l<s) {
    window.alert("Please enter a number larger than the smaller number!");
}
if ((regex_num.test(s)) || (regex_num.test(l))){
    window.alert("please enter valid numbers!");
} else {
    window.alert("Your statement is: " + short_str);
    }
}
</script>
<form>
<input type = "text" id = "t"></input> <br />
<input type = "text" id = "small" size = "5">small number</input> <br />
<input type = "text" id = "large" size = "5">large number</input>
<button type = "button" id = "click" onclick = "sub_str()"> Check </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is occurring because you are calling `document.getElementById` before the element exists on the page. The browser loads everything sequentially. Move your `<script>` below the `<form>`.

Comment: You are doing substr on `t` and _after_ you did the substring you check if its input was valid?

Answer (score 0):

Move DOM element selection into the function, and read its value.
Try this:

```
<p> Input text, and fill in two numbers in the boxes below. </p>
<p> The number on the left must be smaller than the one on the right</p>
<p> Press on the button to see what happens!
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function sub_str() {
    var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var s = document.getElementById("small").value;
    var l = document.getElementById("large").value;
    var short_str = t.substr(s,l);
    var regex_num = /^([0-9]*)$/;
    if (l<s) {
        window.alert("Please enter a number larger than the smaller number!");
    }
    if ((!regex_num.test(s)) || (!regex_num.test(l))){
        window.alert("please enter valid numbers!");
    } else {
        window.alert("Your statement is: " + short_str);
    }
}
</script>
<form>
<input type = "text" id = "t"></input> <br />
<input type = "text" id = "small" size = "5">small number</input> <br />
<input type = "text" id = "large" size = "5">large number</input>
<button type = "button" id = "click" onclick = "sub_str()"> Check </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the inputs' values, not the inputs themselves**

You are interested in what the user typed in your input (that is the input's value), not the input it self. You can get the value of an input by using the `input.value` property.

**Make sure the DOM is loaded when your script is executed**

Make sure your DOM is loaded before doing any operation on it (such as `getElementById`). You should put your script tag at the end of the `<body>` or wrap your code in an [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) handler.

**Compare numbers, not strings**

Also, when you are doing number comparison, make sure you are actually comparing number and not strings. In JavaScript, `"5" > "30"` is `true` (yep...). An input's value is a string. If you want proper number comparison, you must parse the values first (e.g. using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).

```js
console.log('"5" > "30":', "5" > "30");
console.log('5 > 30:', 5 > 30);
console.log('parseInt("5") > parseInt("30"):', parseInt("5") > parseInt("30"));
```

**Fix your tests**

The regexp test is wrong (you show an alert when the values are a number instead of when they are not). Moreover, you could just check the result of [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) instead of regular expression.

**Look after your users**

Finally, you may also consider using inputs of of type `type="number"` instead of `type="text"` for the "small number" and "large number" inputs. `type="number"` will restrict what can be entered directly in the input itself. It will avoid user errors and the frustration of an alert.
By default, `type="number"` also add some controls (i.e. 2 arrows to increment or decrement the entry).
Note that even if you set the type to "number", `input.value` will still be a string that needs to be parsed, but this time, this string will always represent a number.

Similarly, you may programatically and automatically update the "large number" when a user enters a "small number" that is bigger and vice-versa. One less possible error, one less annoying alert.

**Your code fixed** (without the UI suggestions):

```js
var t = document.getElementById("t");
var s = document.getElementById("small");
var l = document.getElementById("large");
function sub_str() {
  var tVal = t.value;
  var sVal = parseInt(s.value, 10); // paseInt will return NaN if the string is not a number.
  var lVal = parseInt(l.value, 10);
  var short_str = tVal.substr(sVal,lVal);
  if (lVal<sVal) {
    window.alert("Please enter a number larger than the smaller number!");
  }
  // Typo here, you want to test if the values are *not* a number.
  else if (isNaN(sVal) || isNaN(lVal)){
    window.alert("please enter valid numbers!");
  } else {
    window.alert("Your statement is: " + short_str);
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Input text, and fill in two numbers in the boxes below. </p>
<p> The number on the left must be smaller than the one on the right</p>
<p> Press on the button to see what happens!</p>
<form>
  <input type = "text" id = "t"></input> <br />
  <input type = "text" id = "small" size = "5">small number</input> <br />
  <input type = "text" id = "large" size = "5">large number</input>
  <button type = "button" id = "click" onclick = "sub_str()"> Check </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues. You are not using `.value` on your elements to get value and then there is always the chance that your code gets executed before the DOM is loaded. So put your processing inside `process()` and then use

```
<body onload="process()">
```

to invoke this function after the document is loaded.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript"> 
    function process() {
        function sub_str() {
        var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
        var s = document.getElementById("small").value;
        var l = document.getElementById("large").value;

            var short_str = t.substr(s,l);
            var regex_num = /^([0-9]*)$/;
            if (l<s) {
                window.alert("Please enter a number larger than the smaller number!");
            }
            if ((regex_num.test(s)) || (regex_num.test(l))){
                window.alert("please enter valid numbers!");
            } else {
                window.alert("Your statement is: " + short_str);
            }
        }
        substr(); // Call the function here
    }
    </script>
```